# Redux y Navigation multiples renderizados en una llamada

Tags: react-native, redux, navigation

Hola escribía porque me sugio un error por asi decirlo, la cuestion es que estoy trabajando con Redux y Navigation.

Pude hacer que se pueda ir de un componente a otro y volver hacia atras, el tema es que por ejemplo si estoy en INICIO (donde hay una FlatList en donde en su render le coloque un `console.log('[IMG]--> '+this.props.radio.imagen)` para ver detalladamente cuando se llamaba al renderizado de los elementos de la lista ) y voy de INICIO->SEGUNDA_VENTANA cuando estoy en la SEGUNDA_VENTANA se vuelve a renderizar lo de INICIO! y si apreto un boton de SEGUNDA_VENTANA tambien se vuelve a renderizar lo de INICIO no entiendo la relacion que hay para que por cada accion que realizo se vueve a renderizar la lista (se que dentro del estado de nav hay un arreglo que va guardando la pila en este caso route[0]=INICIO, route[1]=SEGUNDA_VENTANA).

Ademas si despues de ir a SEGUNDA_VENTANA vuelvo a INICIO (quedando route[0]=INICIO, route[1]=SEGUNDA_VENTANA, route[2]=INICIO ) la lista se rompe no cargandose completamente (cabe aclarar que elemetos de la lista son imagenes obtenidas de internet).

Lo raro es que a medida que voy apilando mas elementos en la navegacion hay acciones (actions) que se ejecutan mas de 1 vez como corresponderia y todo esto comenzo cuando agrege la navegacion a la app.

Espero que se entienda el error, si alguien me podria dar una orientacion de como soluiconarlo seria de mucha ayuda, desde ya muchas gracias.

Dejo el codigo del Reducer:

```
const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(Routes,{headerMode: 'screen'});
const navigateReducer = (state , action) => {
switch (action.type){
    case 'NAVIGATE':
       return AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: action.payload, params: action.params }), state);
    case 'BACK_SCREEN':
        return AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(NavigationActions.back(), state);
    default:
        return AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state);
};
return state;}
```

Comment: Hey Nehuen bienvenido, te sugiero leer [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y tenga buenas respuestas. También, aprovecha y realiza el [tour] para entender mejor el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: A muchas gracias lo revisare